# List JPA where clause in one-to-many relation

Tags: java, angularjs, repository, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

Lab includes some servers. What I am trying to do is listing servers belongs to a lab. For example get servers which belongs to "abc" lab which its id is 1.

Following code gets all servers:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "servers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Server> list() {
    return serverRepository.findAll();
}
```

Entitiy:

```
public class Server {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="LAB_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Lab lab;
}
```

Entitiy;

```
public class Lab {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "LAB_NAME")
    private String labName;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Server> servers;
}
```

angular:

```
$scope.getServers= function () {
    $http.get('services/servers').then(function (response) {
        $scope.servers= response.data;
    });
};
```

Repository:

```
public interface ServerRepository extends JpaRepository<Server, Long>{

}
```

Comment: show us the repository :)

Comment: Your mapping is incorrect. Read the hibernate manual to learn how to map a bidirectional OneToMany association. It should be `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "lab")`. That said, you haven't asked any question, nor described any problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your mappings like so

`Lab` entity

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="lab")
private Set<Server> servers;
```

`Server` entity

```
@ManyToOne
private Lab lab;
```

Now you can write a *JPQL* like so

```
public interface ServerRepository extends JpaRepository<Server, Long>{

    @Query("Select s from Server s where s.lab.labName = :name and s.lab.id = :id")
    List<Server> getServers(@Param("name") String name, @Param("id") Long id);

}
```